# How to recall the uitableviewcell class from tableViewController?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have many uitableviewcell classes using in the tableviewController.
I need to set them up as initialize and set the default values.
I have tried to do something in  (void)viewWillAppear: but it cannot work at all.
Thanks for any advices.

I use the static table in my controller. And each table cell has its own class (uitableviewcell).

Comment: You may want to specify what it is you have tried and what is/isn't working. Are you looking for a way to get a particular cell's class in the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` call?

Comment: tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not the solution for that. but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To customize the table view cells you should use

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```